# Failing to call REST endpoint in vbox

Tags: flutter, dart

I have my spring boot services running in vbox with the ports exposed. I've confirmed this.

When attempting do a post from my flutter app I am receiving the following:

```
Error: XMLHttpRequest error.
    C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 908:28                get current
packages/http/src/browser_client.dart 71:22                                                                                    <fn>
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1687:54                                              runUnary
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 160:18                                        handleValue
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 767:44                                        handleValueCallback
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 796:13                                        _propagateToListeners
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 593:7                                         [_complete]
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/stream_pipe.dart 61:11                                         _cancelAndValue
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/stream.dart 1232:7                                             <fn>
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 334:14  _checkAndCall
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 339:39  dcall
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/html/dart2js/html_dart2js.dart 37332:58                              <fn>


    at Object.createErrorWithStack (http://localhost:63034/dart_sdk.js:5074:12)
    at Object._rethrow (http://localhost:63034/dart_sdk.js:38925:16)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:63034/dart_sdk.js:38921:13)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:63034/dart_sdk.js:38778:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:63034/dart_sdk.js:38784:13)
    at http://localhost:63034/dart_sdk.js:34519:9
```

The code where I make the request is as follows:

```
void _registerBuild() async {
    Map<String, String> headers = {
      'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
      'Accept' : 'application/json'
    };
    Map data = {
      'buildingName': buildingName,
      'erf': erf,
      'addressRoad': addressRoad,
      'addressSuburb': addressSuburb,
      'addressCity': addressCity,
      'addressProvince': addressProvince,
      'addressCountry': addressCountry,
      'addressPostalCode': addressPostalCode
    };

    var response = await http.post(Uri.http('192.168.1.102:9081', '/trusteeman/building/register'),
        headers: headers,
        body: jsonEncode(data));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print("**************************************\n");
      print(response.body);
    }
  }
```

I've tried using the IP address of: 10.0.2.2 but receive the same error.

Any help appreciated

EDIT 1 - I've built the backend with WSL and started them up but still having the same issue

Comment: Does it has `CORS` enabled?

Comment: I don't believe so. It's this s setting or configuration I need to add?

Comment: @PrinceSanjivy you're correct. Added debug logging to the service and I can see the 403 error now. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Was a CORS issue. debug logging showed it on the server side.